# Wrapping code for PIG script,Hive Queries and Corresponding MapReduce code

Tags: mapreduce, hive, apache-pig, bigdata

I am working on 2 datasets.I have MapReduced those,then Operated on output by means of PIG & HIVE.I want to execute all these steps at once in sequence.How should I wrap these things into a single scritp i.e Map Reduce code,followed by PIG script and finally few Hive queries.

Thanks,
Ketan

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap those in Oozie workflow.
Oozie enable you to run collection of actions arrange in a DAG - check [this link](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/DG_Overview.html)

They have good documentation so you can start with that.